# Default remote for master != default remote for any branches I create

Tags: git

Say I have two remotes:

```
* official  (this is the official repo, no write permission)
* my_fork   (write permission)
```

I would like to set the default remote of my `master` branch to `official`(so that I can keep track of changes there easily), and set `my_fork` as the default remote for any branches that I create.

How can I do this with my `.git/config` or `git config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The fetch remote

There is no "pullDefault" (or, more properly, fetchDefault).  This means that when you *create* each branch, you must set its remote individually.  For instance, you might run:

```
git checkout -b keep-working-on --track my_fork/existing-branch
```

(`--track` is the default, I included it just to be explicilt here), or:

```
git checkout -b newbr
git branch --set-upstream-to my_fork/newbr-name-there
```

or:

```
git checkout -b newbr
git push -u my_fork newbr:newbr-name-there
```

to create `newbr` and set its upstream to `my_fork/newbr-name-there` (and, for the `push -u` version, create `newbr-name-there` on the upstream now, assuming it does not yet exist).

Note that in the case when you wind up creating a branch with a non-`-b`-flagged `git checkout`, as for instance is always true for the branch (usually `master`) created at the end of `git clone`, git:

1. searches for the name as an existing local branch, but this fails (e.g., there is no `master` yet in a new clone)—if the search does not fail we're not creating a branch after all and none of this applies;
2. searches through all the currently-defined remotes and their remote-tracking branches to see if any of them are named appropriately (e.g., `origin/master`, `official/master`, `my_fork/master`; of course in a new clone, only `origin` exists, but git does this for *every* `git checkout`, assuming we even get through step 1); and finally
3. if there is *exactly one* such branch, creates a new branch whose name is the name you gave (`master`) that is configured with that remote (`origin`) and corresponding remote-tracking branch (`origin/master`), as if you had run `git checkout -b master --track origin/master`.

This is why there is no `remote.fetchDefault`: the correct default remote is computed automatically, if there is an obvious correct remote.  Otherwise git expects you to set or choose it, using the `--set-upstream-to` or `git push -u` methods if you cannot choose an existing branch (e.g., to make new branch `newbr`).

#### The push remote

But, per [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> branch.<name>.remote
>
> When on branch <name>, it tells git fetch and git push which remote to fetch from/push to. The remote to push to may be overridden with remote.pushDefault (for all branches). The remote to push to, for the current branch, may be further overridden by branch.<name>.pushRemote. If no remote is configured, or if you are not on any branch, it defaults to origin for fetching and remote.pushDefault for pushing. Additionally, . (a period) is the current local repository (a dot-repository), see branch.<name>.merge's final note below.
>
> branch.<name>.pushRemote
>
> When on branch <name>, it overrides branch.<name>.remote for pushing. It also overrides remote.pushDefault for pushing from branch <name>. When you pull from one place (e.g. your upstream) and push to another place (e.g. your own publishing repository), you would want to set remote.pushDefault to specify the remote to push to for all branches, and use this option to override it for a specific branch.

This means that regardless of how you handle the fetch remote, you can set `remote.pushDefault` to `my_fork`, which will make all branches default to pushing to remote `my_fork`.  Then, set `branch.master.pushRemote` to `official`, so that branch `master` will push to `official` instead of using the default `my_fork` remote.